# htaccess convert request to clean url and add slash at the end of the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK , i searched for this for more than 4 days and more than 20 posts even here in stach or in another websites but without any kind of success

First here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC]
```

I tried many codes but this one worked with me as i can call this request and works with me

www.example.com/pagename => www.example.com/index.php?page=pagename

here is my questions and please provide me with information "in detail" to understand the code well

1- how to convert my request automatically from  www.example.com/index.php?page=pagename  to www.example.com/pagename

2- if i tried to add slash at the end it shows me the page but without any images or styling
i mean something like this www.example.com/pagename => works
www.example.com/pagename/ => doesn't work

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

For your first part you need a 301 rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

For the second part just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Ok i added your code in my .htaccess file and i entered my url as like this /index.php?page=pagename , it opened my page but the url still the same one

Comment: This rule should be very first rule in your root .htaccess.

Comment: This is fully tested rule taken from a live website so this rule definitely works. I made an update, try updated code.

Comment: Thanks buddy this one worked but there a problem that when i go to that directory it redirect to localhost/pagename .. i want to redirect it to localhost/script/pagename , for the second part , isn't there any other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Where is `/script/` in path coming from? You never mentioned it before.

Comment: OK i solved that path problem , but now my problem is on the second part , how to make it work without including the full path ? :)